# Literature about In-Memory Database Systems

Tags: architecture, in-memory-database

I am currently writing my bachelor thesis on IMDBS and would like to ask if any of you have any recommendations for literature which summarizes the technical conception/architecture of IMDBS as apparently I am not able to find articles, papers, books etc which are covering the physical architecture or to In-Memory Database Systems but just on logical data storage, indexing etc.

Any recommendations would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
toni

Comment: [Google Scholar is good!](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=in+memory+database+systems&btnG=)

Answer (score 2):

The CMU advanced database course is about building an in-memory DBMS. It has been released on Youtube. Each lecture has some notes and references.

Comment: thanks a lot. will definitely check it out!